# Convert configurable product to bundle product

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, bundled-product, conversion

I installed magento and sample data for that and now what i need to do is convert configurable product named 'CN Clogs Beach/Garden Clog' in to bundled product like
'Magento Red Furniture Set'

Configurable product is available at Home / CN Clogs Beach/Garden Clog in front side.

Bundles product is available at Home / Furniture / Living Room / Magento Red Furniture Set.

Any help regarding this will be appreciable.

Comment: In the sample data `Magento Red Furniture Set` is a grouped product not a bundle.

Comment: correct my mistake...

Answer (score 3):

I tried this just for fun and it seams to work but I didn't test all the implications of this modification.
Anyway, **you shouldn't do this in production. The safest way is to add your products manually.**.
As stated in the comment `Magento Red Furniture Set` is a grouped product not a bundle one.
To change a configurable product to grouped do this.
Identify the product id. For me it is `83`. Change the product type with this query:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `type` = 'grouped' WHERe `entity_id` = 83
```

Now identify the simple products associated to the configurable one.

SELECT `child_id` FROM `catalog_product_relation` WHERE `parent_id` = 83;

I got these results: `29, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92`
Then insert one row for each value in the table `catalog_product_link`.

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_link` VALUES (NULL, 83, 29, 3), (NULL, 83, 84, 3),(NULL, 83, 85, 3),(NULL, 83, 86, 3),(NULL, 83, 87, 3),(NULL, 83, 88, 3),(NULL, 83, 89, 3),(NULL, 83, 90, 3),(NULL, 83, 91, 3),(NULL, 83, 92, 3)
```

For each row you insert `83` is the main product id, `29` (or `84`, or `85`...) is the child id and `3` is the relation type id (grouped).

Delete the child ids from `catalog_product_relation`.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_relation` WHERE `parent_id` = 83;
```

Delete the child ids from `catalog_product_super_link`.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_super_link` where `parent_id` = 83;
```

Like I said, this seams to work for me. You can test but back-up your db first.
But in case I wasn't clear at the top of this answer. **DON'T EVER DO THIS IN PRODUCTION. PRODUCT TYPES ARE NOT MEANT TO BE CHANGED**

Comment: I have to change grouped products to configurable. Which table should I refer to figure out the relation type id please?

Comment: Or, in other words, how do you know "3 is the relation type id (grouped)". ?

Comment: @zarun. See the constants in class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link`

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest taking a look at this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/displaze-change-product-type.html

Very well reviewed and tested on production.

Comment: This extension does not exist anymore or has the link changed? Please could you update it if possible?

Comment: I believe this is the developer profile: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/Aftab%20Naveed
Try to contact the developer and ask for a copy by clicking the `Email` link under the `Developer Info` label

Comment: The developer replied that he could not keep up with changes in guidelines in the magento store and they put his extension down and now he has no copies of it anywhere with him. Strange but that's what he said. :( Thanks for trying to help @moose