# Change product type from grouped to configurable

Tags: extensions, configurable-product, grouped-products, product-type

There are grouped products on an existing shop which I now want to display as configurable products depending on their simple product weight.

The way it works now is also okay but I have a usability issue that users have to figure out where to enter their quantity for the exact weighted product they want to order. **For example**, if I have a grouped product with simple products that are 100g, 200g, 400g, 800g, 1000g, and they want to order 200g, they have to leave 0 on the quantity box of all other product weights and just 1 (or 2,3 etc.) on the box corresponding to 200g. This would be so much easier if there was a dropdown box with the weight selectable as dropdown and a quantity box next to it which I can achieve with a configurable product setup.

**Question:** Is there any way this can be achieved programmatically or with an extension or with something on the database?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) posted an answer with a different type of product which can work:

You can follow the answer

[Convert configurable product to bundle product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/convert-configurable-product-to-bundle-product/14521#14521)

Comment: As of now, this is the closest that I can consider as any help closer to finding an answer. Thanks @osrecio.